# template not found for Django homepage

Tags: python, django

I'm still new to Django and I am trying to create a small website as practice. However I am currently running into this error. If someone could explain where I went wrong and teach me how I can fix this that would be great! I'm new and the Documentation can be hard to read sometimes =[

Please let me know if there is anything else I need to add!

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/home/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')

Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/home/bradford/Development/Django/pub_pic/~/Development/Django/pub_pic/templates/homepage_template/home.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/homepage_template/home.html (File does not exist)



Traceback:
File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/pub_pic/homepage/views.py" in index
  9.    return render(request,'homepage_template/home.html')
File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  53.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  170.         t = get_template(template_name)
File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  146.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
  139.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /home/
Exception Value: homepage_template/home.html
```

I have a template named `home.html` and it is in the directory `pub_pic/templates/homepage_template/home.html`

My pub_pic urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'home/',include('homepage.urls', namespace = 'home')),
)
```

My homepage urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from homepage import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),



)
```

homepage/views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response

#from homepage.models import 

def index(request):
#   template = loader.get_template('homepage/index.html')
    return render(request,'homepage_template/home.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the value of your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting. But looking at the error message, it looks like you're using `~/...` there. Don't do that: use the full path - `/home/bradford/Development/Django/pub_pic/templates`.

Comment: in my `TEMPLATE_DIRS` it is `~/Development/Django/pub_pic/templates`

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. Don't use `~`, use the full path.

Comment: Could you briefly explain what is going on here? I sorta just put things together without really knowing it.My guess is that in my `pub_pic/urls.py` creates `localhost:8000/home/`. It also `includes()` everything in `homepage/urls.py`. Inside the `url()` of `homepage/urls.py` it grabs the `index()` function in `views.index` renders `index.html`. I'm still learning Django could you tell me if my logic is correct?

Comment: Although this works it is a really bad idea. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Please **do not include the full path** in settings as the accepted answer suggests. This is the "anti-django" way of doing things, even if it does work.

In Django you can either have one templates folder for a project or one templates folder per app. The latter allows you to move apps from project to project (which is how they are supposed to work) but the former can provide simplicity for monolithic once-off projects.

You DO NOT need to and should not specify the absolute path. In your settings, if you want a single templates directory for your project use something like:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
,)
```

This is basically saying your templates are in a folder called 'templates' that is in the main BASE_DIR path. In this example that would be the root directory where the manage.py resides. Now just make a folder called 'templates' in this root directory and throw your HTML in there (arranged in subfolders if you like).

Templates can then be loaded as simply as

```
templt = get_template('mytemplate.html)
```

Where it is presumed that mytemplate.html file resides directly in the templates/ folder off the root directory. You can use subfolders and if you do you should specify them in the quotes e.g. 'mysubdir/mytemplate.html'

As an alternative, you can allow each app to have its own templates
In this case you must have the following in settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [

{

    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',

    'DIRS': [],

    'APP_DIRS': True,

    'OPTIONS': {

        'context_processors': [

            'django.template.context_processors.debug',

            'django.template.context_processors.request',

            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',

            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

        ],

    },

},

]
```

The key here is

```
'APP_DIRS': True,
```

This ([according to the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/templates/)) instructs the system to look in each app for a 'templates' folder. Your project would then look something like (presuming a project name of mybigproject)

> /home/myaccount/mybigproject/myapp1/templates/

and

> /home/myaccount/mybigproject/myapp2/templates/

By contrast in the first scenario (single templates folder) it would just be

> /home/myaccount/mybigproject/templates/

However the important thing to take away is that you **STILL REFERENCE IT AS**:

```
templt = get_template('mytemplate.html)
```

Django will search through all the app folders for you.
If it still gives you a file not found error it is a configuration thing.

If you specify a full path, now you need to change that path as you move PC's (e.g. shared projects), projects or apps which is a disaster.

Answer (score 3):

In your settings.py file you should use below code.

```
 
#settings.py
import os
# Full filesystem path to the project.
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Installed Applications:
('homepage_template.apps.Homepage_templateConfig', #add this line
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
```